# IBM Cloud dashDB Timezone

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

The IBM Cloud (former Bluemix) dashDB service uses UTC as timezone. You cannot change that setting as far as I know. My data is from a different timezone.

How do I either set the timezone for my data (table or column) or structure/format my data such that dashDB will properly compare my values?
(e.g. matching "today")

Comment: Basically there is no support for time that includes timezone in the schema for the database.  All time in database is UTC time and any conversion or comparison is DIY.

Answer (score 1):

dashDB has functions like [`TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061917.html) and [`FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061916.html) to convert between UTC and a specific timezone. The following query returns the current time for Los Angeles/San Francisco:

```
SELECT from_utc_timestamp (current timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles')
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

If you wrap a `date` around you get the current date (a.k.a. "today") for that specific timezone:

```
SELECT date(from_utc_timestamp (current timestamp, 'America/Los_Angeles'))
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

There are many functions to help with date/time arithmetics and you can add/subtract years/months/.../seconds from any date/time value. My recommendation would be to store timestamps that have been converted to UTC and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no support for timezone in time data."  And stackoverflow is stupid to insist that an answer must be 30 characters or more.  No means no.

Answer (score 0):

Check the dashDB Knowledge center on different options you can explore w.r.t timezone.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/timezone?scope=SS6NHC